# Lost settings menu and unity lenses after uninstalling Gnome 3

Tags: unity, gnome, package-management, lenses

I installed gnome 3 in Ubuntu 13.10- I later decided to remove it.  Now Everything has gone. When I right click the desktop I can't access the settings and all the unity lenses are missing apart from the Social and network messages. So I can't access any programs from the unity launcher only what I have pinned to the side bar.

In the terminal I tried

```
apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

but I get the following message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gnome-control-center : Depends: gnome-control-center-data (< 1:3.7) but 1:3.8.3-0ubuntu1~raring2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I guess when I removed Gnome 3 it broke some packages and I am not sure how to get them back.

I installed gnome 3 from the PPA

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` outputs

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-control-center-unity but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

-f install outputs

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt-get check` outputs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done



sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude -fy install ubuntu-desktop
```

It says 6 packages were installed but they were not installed.

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gnome-control-center{ab} gnome-control-center-signon{a} 
gnome-control-center-unity ubuntu-desktop webaccounts-extension-common{a} 
xul-ext-webaccounts 
0 packages upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 655 kB/729 kB of archives. After unpacking 4,667 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-control-center : Depends: gnome-control-center-data (< 1:3.7) but
1:3.8.3-0ubuntu1~raring2 is installed.

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version: 
1)  gnome-control-center [Not Installed]                
2)  gnome-control-center-signon [Not Installed]         
3)  gnome-control-center-unity [Not Installed]          
4)  ubuntu-desktop [Not Installed]                      
5)  webaccounts-extension-common [Not Installed]        
6)  xul-ext-webaccounts [Not Installed]                 

Leave the following dependencies unresolved:          
7)   ubuntu-desktop recommends gnome-control-center-unity


  No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
  0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
 Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude -fy install ubuntu-desktop~?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and see if it reinstalls the package that might have been removed.

I think `sudo apt-get -f install` might fix broken packages.

Since you used a PPA you need to do a PPA Purge. There's some information regarding installing Gnome 3.8 in Ubuntu 13.04, and how do revert here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/gnome-38-beta-available-in-ppa-for.html

There's additional information regarding Ubuntu 13.10 and Gnome 3.10 and purging here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html

I'm guessing a purge at this stage might not be successful, but try that first.

Comment: added outputs into original post